# Vue: click outside directive is triggered inside the element with v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```html
<template>
  <div id="app" style="display: flex; gap: 10px">
    <div
      v-for="(item, index) in myItems"
      :key="index"
      class="my-item"
      v-click-outside="showClickAway"
    >
      {{ item }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
Vue.directive("click-outside", {
  bind: function (el, binding, vnode) {
    el.clickOutsideEvent = function (event) {
      // here I check that click was outside the el and his children
      if (!(el == event.target || el.contains(event.target))) {
        // and if it did, call method provided in attribute value
        vnode.context[binding.expression](event);
      }
    };
    document.body.addEventListener("click", el.clickOutsideEvent);
  },
  unbind: function (el) {
    document.body.removeEventListener("click", el.clickOutsideEvent);
  }
});
```

You can go to: https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-ellis-rq5si1?file=/src/App.vue

1. click a red item of boxes
2. see console

The expected result is actually pretty straightforward.
It should log outside the element when clicked outside.
Would be cooler if the solution can log once when clicked outside

I tried other things but get stuck.
Please help

Answer (score 1):

I did some mathematics not to print several logs here:

```js
this.counter++;
if (this.counter % this.myItems.length === 0) {
   console.log("showClickAway");
}
```

And, I changed this row:

```js
if ((!(el === event.target || el.contains(event.target)) && event.target.className !== 'my-item'))
```

**An example:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    myItems: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    counter: 0,
  },
  methods: {
    showClickAway() {
      this.counter++;
      if (this.counter % this.myItems.length === 0) {
        console.log("showClickAway");
      }
    }
  },
  directives: {
    "click-outside": {
      bind: (el, binding, vnode) => {
        el.clickOutsideEvent = (event) => {
          // here I check that click was outside the el and his children
          if ((!(el === event.target || el.contains(event.target)) && event.target.className !== 'my-item')) {
            // and if it did, call method provided in attribute value
            vnode.context[binding.expression](event);
          }
        };
        document.addEventListener("click", el.clickOutsideEvent);
      },
      unbind: (el) => {
        document.removeEventListener("click", el.clickOutsideEvent);
      },
    },
  },
});
```

```css
#app {
  font-family: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

.my-item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app" style="display: flex; gap: 10px">
  <div v-for="(item, index) in myItems" v-click-outside="showClickAway" :key="item" class="my-item">
    {{ item }}
  </div>
</div>
```